# Because giphy_get >=3.0.0-pre.1 depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends ond

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

Resolving dependencies...
Because giphy_get >=3.0.0-pre.1 depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, giphy_get >=3.0.0-pre.1 requires intl 0.18.1.
So, because flutter_theme depends on both intl ^0.17.0 and giphy_get ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1

Here, is my pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: flutter_theme
description: A new Flutter project.


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  #Base
  get: ^4.6.5
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  dartx: ^1.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  intl: ^0.18.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  story_view: ^0.14.0
  audioplayers: ^1.1.1
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  flip_card: ^0.6.0
  advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.1
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.1
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^20.4.38
  dio: ^4.0.6
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+3
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  local_auth: ^1.1.0
  pin_input_text_field: ^4.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  convex_bottom_bar: ^3.1.0+1
  file_picker: ^5.2.3
  path:
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  video_player: ^2.4.9
  just_audio: ^0.9.31
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  http: ^0.13.5
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
  chewie: ^1.3.5
  #camera: ^0.10.0+4
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  flutter_contacts: ^1.1.5+1
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.1
  wechat_assets_picker: ^8.3.1+1
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  pinput: ^2.2.23
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  image_cropper: ^3.0.1
  giphy_get: ^3.0.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.1.0
  wakelock: ^0.6.2
  bubble: ^1.2.1
  overlay_support: ^2.1.0
  camera: ^0.10.3+1
  awesome_notifications: ^0.7.4+1
  audio_video_progress_bar: ^0.11.0
  open_filex: ^4.3.2
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  video_compress: ^3.1.2
  light_compressor: ^2.0.1
```

Comment: i am trying with upgrade intl: ^0.18.0 after that showing Because local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and flutter_theme depends on intl ^0.18.0, local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 is forbidden. So, because flutter_theme depends on local_auth ^1.1.0, version solving failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.